# Cómo llamar una función en jQuery hecha por mí?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema, quiero llamar a una función creada por mí para no repetir código. Tengo varios formularios que verificar y hay muchos elementos que llevan la misma verificación. Las funciones yo las creé en JS y funciona sin problema.

Cuando quise cambiar para jQuery, las funciones dejaron de funcionar. Arriba hice una validación para un input que funciona bien, pero si quiero hacerlo con los demás tendría que repetir código y es lo que no quiero.

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

```
//------------jQuery--------------\\
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_eliminar_postgrado").click(function() {
        var exprecionNumero = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var cod_post = $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").val();

        //if (!$("#txt_codigo_postgrado").isNumeric()) {
        if (cod_post == "" || !exprecionNumero.test(cod_post)) {
            $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#alerta_post").show();
            $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").removeClass("is-invalid");
            $("#alerta_post").hide();
            $('input[type="text"]').val('');
            return true;
        }
    })


})  


//-----------Funciones Generales-----------\\

function validarNumero(numero){
    var exprecion = /^[0-9]+$/;

    if (numero.val == "" || !exprecion.test(numero.val)) {

        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo donde llama a validarNumero()

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambia las condiciones de tu if por una llamada a la función, enviando la variable a evaluar:

```
//------------jQuery--------------\\
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_eliminar_postgrado").click(function() {
        var cod_post = $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").val();
        if(validarNumero(cod_post)) {
            // Número válido
            $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").removeClass("is-invalid");
            $("#alerta_post").hide();
            $('input[type="text"]').val('');
            return true;
        } else {
            $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").addClass("is-invalid");
            $("#alerta_post").show();
            $("#txt_codigo_postgrado").focus();
            return false;
        }

    })
})  

//-----------Funciones Generales-----------\\

function validarNumero(numero){
    var expresion = /^[0-9]+$/;

    if (numero.val == "" || !expresion.test(numero.val)) {

        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya funciona, gracias x dar respuesta al problema. Al final tenía 2 errores, x eso no me funcionaba. 1.) No había llamado a la función k fue lo k uds m dijeron. 2.) La función creada estaba en conflicto con cod_pod y número.val. Solo tuve k quitar el .val y todo funcionó. Gracias nuevamente. Ahora, otra pregunta. jQuery admite variables globales??